# Retain value of disabled item when building it within array

Tags: angular

I'm building a form array like this:

```
buildAnimations(arr) {
        var resultArr = [];
        arr.forEach(x => {
            resultArr.push(this.fBuilder.group({
                name: [x.name, [Validators.required]],
                frameRate: [x.frameRate, [Validators.required]],
                loop: [x.loop],
                pickUpItemDelay: [x.pickUpItemDelay, x.type == 0 ? Validators.required : undefined],
                required: [x.required],
                type: [{ value: x.type, disabled: x.required == true ? true : false }, [Validators.required]],
                filesUploaded: [x.filesUploaded, Validators.requiredTrue]
            }))
        });
        return this.fBuilder.array(resultArr);
    }
```

However on save, I'm not remembering the real value of `"type"` since it is disabled. I know I can remember the value if I went through each individual record like this: `this.myForm.controls['type'].disable({onlySelf: true});` but is there a way I can do it whilst constructing and looping through the array in the first place?

I'm after something like: `type: [{ value: x.type, disabled: x.required == true ? true : false, onlySelf: true }, [Validators.required]],`

Comment: You mean getting the value of disabled form controls?

Comment: @Chellappanவ well if I save the form it will think "type" is null when it actually has a value just because it's null. There should be a way I can disable it but have the value on save somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Angular FormGroup has [getRawvalue()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getrawvalue) method use that to get all form values along with disabled control.

**Try this:**

```
onSubmit(){
  this.myForm.getRawValue();
}
```